Directory name is not maintained during zip and unzip when they contain an extension
I am trying to zip an app directory via node.js (actually is an electron app). The name of the directory is "MovieSwift.app" (it's an iOS app) using the "zip-local" package.
But when I unzip it afterwards, to see if it contains the files, the directory is named "MovieSwift", which is a problem in my case, because the unzipping part is done by some external API that relies on the zipped directory having a .app extension.
I also tried with the package "zip-dir". Same problem.
Any idea of which package I could use instead? Or some workaround?
Here is the code:
//var zipdir = require('zip-dir')
const zipper = require('zip-local')
// `buffer` is the buffer of the zipped file
const zipFileName = basename(appFilePath).replace('.app', '.zip')
const zipFilePath = getTempDirPath() + sep() + zipFileName
console.log('Zipping .app directory to: ', zipFilePath)
//await zipdir(appFilePath, { saveTo: zipFilePath })
await zipper.sync.zip(appFilePath).compress().save(zipFilePath)


How are you determining that the directory is named MovieSwift? If you are looking at it in macOS finder, by default the .app extension will not be shown, even though it is there. There is a Finder Settings option, Advanced, "Show all filename extensions" that you can check.

I checked that file extension. I can also see it in the terminal that it's called "MovieSwift.app". After unzipping only a "MovieSwift" dir is there. .app is missing

You would need to show your code that does the zipping.

You need to set the output name to "MovieSwift.app.zip", After unzipping it should be "MovieSwift.app" If you replace ".app" with ".zip", why do you expect it to magical return to those name?

The name of the directory should be encoded inside of the zip file IMO. The name of the zip file should NOT matter IMO.

Why are you doing .replace('.app', '.zip')? Just create the zip with the extension of .app if that is what you need and rename your app folder or create a parent folder.

@stoefln The name of the directory should be encoded inside of the zip file IMO Where is that written/defined? I see absolutely nothing that does/define this. Post a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "zip-local" does not give a flying ... about that. Is this a iOS feature? If so you cant expect other compression tools to honor that. As simple is that.


when I unzip it afterwards, to see if it contains the files, the directory is named "MovieSwift"

Because you did .replace('.app', '.zip').

the unzipping part is done by some external API that relies on the zipped directory having a .app extension.

Then name/locate your directory to be zipped appropriately.
You can use zip-local on a parent folder of MovieSwift.app.
Given this directory structure:
.
├── SwiftApp/
│   └── MovieSwift.app/
│       └── file.txt
├── zip.js
└── package.json

You can write a script with zip-local inside of zip.js to get what you want.
zip.js
zipper.sync.zip('./SwiftApp/').compress().save(`${somePreferredPath}.zip`)

And have the external API unzip that archive to get MovieSwift.app directory.
Alternatively, put your app in a folder named MovieSwift
zipper.snyc.zip('./MovieSwift/').compress().save(`${somePreferredPath}.app`)

Basically, you can run zip-local and use a .app or .zip extension on the archive.
